# how to optimize the processing time of the "run generate" command

Tags: nuxt.js

I have 5 requests and 14 dynamic routes today that represents about 60 pages to generate

```
generate: {
    interval: 100,
    routes: function (callback) {

        let routes = []
        axios.all([
            axios.get(process.env.API_URL +  '/web_pages'),
            axios.get(process.env.API_URL +  '/tags'),
            axios.get(process.env.API_URL +  '/articles'),
            axios.get(process.env.API_URL +  '/accommodation_types'),
            axios.get(process.env.API_URL +  '/accommodations'),
        ])
        .then(axios.spread(
            function (
                web_pages
                , tags
                , articles
                , accommodation_types
                , accommodations
        ) {
            web_pages.data['hydra:member'].map((webPage) => {
                    routes.push({ route: '/' + webPage.slug
                        , payload: { webPage: webPage, locale: 'fr' } })
                    routes.push({ route: '/en/' + en['WebPage'][webPage.slug]
                        , payload: { webPage: webPage, locale: 'en' } })
            })
            tags.data['hydra:member'].map((tag) => {

                routes.push({ route: '/actualite/' + tag.slug
                    , payload: { tag: tag, locale: 'fr' }
                })
                routes.push({ route: '/en/news/' + en['Tag'][tag.slug]
                    , payload: { tag: tag, locale: 'en' }
                })
            })
            articles.data['hydra:member'].map((article) => {

                routes.push({
                    route: '/actualite/' + article.category.slug + '/' + article.slug
                    , payload: { article: article, locale: 'fr' } })
                routes.push({
                    route: '/en/news/' + en['Tag'][article.category.slug] + '/' + en['Article'][article.slug]
                    , payload: { article: article, locale: 'en' }  })
            })
            accommodation_types.data['hydra:member'].map((type) => {

                routes.push({ route: '/location/' + type.slug
                    , payload: { type: type, locale: 'fr' }
                })
                routes.push({ route: '/en/renting/' + en['AccommodationType'][type.slug]
                    , payload: { type: type, locale: 'en' }
                })

                routes.push({ route: '/vente/' + type.slug
                    , payload: { type: type, locale: 'fr' }
                })
                routes.push({ route: '/en/selling/' + en['AccommodationType'][type.slug]
                    , payload: { type: type, locale: 'en' }
                })
            })
            accommodations.data['hydra:member'].map((accommodation) => {
                routes.push({ route: '/location/' + accommodation.type.slug + '/' + accommodation.slug
                    , payload: { type : accommodation.type, accommodation: accommodation, locale: 'fr' }
                })
                routes.push({ route: '/en/renting/' + en['AccommodationType'][accommodation.type.slug] + '/' + en['Accommodation'][accommodation.slug]
                    , payload: { type : accommodation.type, accommodation: accommodation, locale: 'en' }
                })
                routes.push({ route: '/vente/' + accommodation.type.slug + '/' + accommodation.slug
                    , payload: { type : accommodation.type, accommodation: accommodation, locale: 'fr' }
                })
                routes.push({ route: '/en/selling/' + en['AccommodationType'][accommodation.type.slug] + '/' + en['Accommodation'][accommodation.slug]
                    , payload: { type : accommodation.type, accommodation: accommodation, locale: 'en' }
                })
            })

            callback(null, routes)
        })).catch(callback)
    }
}
```

the processing time can last 15 minutes and sometimes I have errors "socket hang up" see errors of route not generated, for me it seems to me very long more I must get error, I think I will proceed as below to go to the end of error-free processing

```
$ yarn generate --no-build -r web_pages
$ rsync -auv production-build/ dist/*
$ yarn generate --no-build -r articles
$ rsync -auv production-build/ dist/*
$ yarn generate --no-build -r tag
$ rsync -auv production-build/ dist/*
$ yarn generate --no-build -r accommodation_types
$ rsync -auv production-build/ dist/*
$ yarn generate --no-build -r accommodation
$ rm production-build/* -Rf
```

does anyone have a better method to optimize the processing time and not get a "socket hang up" error?